# How do I separate input lines in a file in string value and integer keys for Hash tables?

Tags: java, parsing, hashtable

I want to get parse (if possible) the partition that contains the string that is a number(i.e."95") but I could accept any strategy to do it. my code works for hashMaps

to not make this lengthy, this is how the lines in the input file look like:

Kostas_Antetokounmpo 37

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "roster.txt";
        String row;
        Integer row1;
        HashTable_NBA<Integer,String> roster = new HashTable_NBA<>();
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        while ((row = read.readLine()) != null){

            String[] partition = row.split(" ", 2);
            if(partition.length >= 2){
                Integer key = Integer.parseInt(partition[1]);
                String value = partition[0];
                roster.put(key, value);

            }
        }

            System.out.println(roster);


    }
}

//EDIT
//the errors are these

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "37   "
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at HashTable_NBA.main(HashTable_NBA.java:161)
```

Comment: I could include my whole code , but that's my class for hash table for handling separate chaining. do you think is helpful to include the whole code?

Comment: Nah.  What do your rows look like?

Comment: just like the example I included in the op

Comment: Duh.  So what are you seeing? Your code looks okay.

Comment: `String[] stringParts = yourString.trim().split("(?<=\\s+)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess but I am assuming there could be more than one space between the values.  And I remove the `2` from the split command.  That was causing problems.

```
        while ((row = read.readLine()) != null){

            String[] partition = row.split("\\s+");
            if(partition.length >= 2){
                Integer key = Integer.parseInt(partition[1]);
                String value = partition[0];
                roster.put(key, value);

            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the errors, look the edit. thanks for your feedback btw

Comment: You have trailing spaces in your file.  Use row.trim().split("\\s+", 2)` and see if that helps.  I'll amend my answer to add that.

Comment: Actually, if you got rid of the 2 in your split statement, that would work also as the end delimiter would be ignored. Split will only split what is there.

Comment: thanks, no errors but this is what gets printed to the console : HashTable_NBA@b065c63

Comment: That is because the `toString()` method is not overridden to print the contents.  That means you will need to iterate over the hash table to print the data.  I could guess how to do it but I don't know if that implementation of HashTable has the same methods as the Java API.  Clearly, in one aspect it doesn't.  Is there a `keySet()` method?

Comment: no there's not a keyset method, when I implemented this in hashmap i used that. which method would be easier to overwrite if I have to?

Comment: I would try and provide a list of keys or a set of keys so you can use them to print out the key and value.  Another option is to save the key in a list or array when you read them in from the file.  Depending on your needs of course, it is up to you.  Another remote possibility would be an `entrySet()`.

Comment: thank you guys I would have to post another thread I ran into a different issue